# Wordpress Search on Multiple wp sites

Tags: customization, search

I want to search different wordpress installations on the same domain al at once.

Whe have some wp installations running different shops. I want users to search in shop One and find also results from shop2 and shop3 and so on.

Anyone have some ideas on how to do that what code do i need to let wordpress search in all the databases.

Kind regards Rene

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a look at the [`posts_clauses`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8bd9659d0d4e57b03262d88dc9c270b44d9164f1/wp-includes/query.php#L2661) filter. There're more [*specialised* filters as well](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8bd9659d0d4e57b03262d88dc9c270b44d9164f1/wp-includes/query.php#L2652) like `posts_where`, but you'll finally end up using the all in one filter.

Then you can inspect the outcome using the `'posts_selection'` hook [right below that](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8bd9659d0d4e57b03262d88dc9c270b44d9164f1/wp-includes/query.php#L2667), or the [`posts_results`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8bd9659d0d4e57b03262d88dc9c270b44d9164f1/wp-includes/query.php#L2750) filter a bit later on.

There's as well the [`posts_search`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8bd9659d0d4e57b03262d88dc9c270b44d9164f1/wp-includes/query.php#L2263) filter as searches use a bit different SQL strings.

The final result can be inspected using `$wpdb->last_query`, or in case of an error using `$wpdb->last_error`.

If a user is logged in and should be able to search all the blogs he's registered to, [`get_blogs_of_user()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_blogs_of_user/) might be an option. Retrieving a general list of all blogs [isn't hard as well](http://bueltge.de/liste-aller-blogs-in-wordpress-multisite/2602/).